# Faster way to solve an integral

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

I have to solve the following integral
$$
\int_{-\frac{W}{2}}^{\frac{W}{2}}
\,
\text{d}\,\varepsilon
\,
\sqrt{1 - 4\,\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{W}\right)^{2}}
\,
\frac{1}{E - \varepsilon}
$$
i started to solve it by substitution of variable
$\frac{2\,\varepsilon}{W}=\sin\left(t\right)$
and i have to solve
$$
\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}
\,
\text{d}\,t
\,
\cos^{2}\left(t\right)
\,
\frac{1}{\frac{2\,E}{W} - \sin\left(t\right)}
$$
and subsequently using Weistrass replacement
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution.

This solution is not so immediate
I hope there are faster analytical routes,

Thanks for the attention

Comment: Your proposed way forward seems reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

We can make the Weierstrass substitution a bit simpler by writing

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\cos^2(t)}{(2E/W)-\sin(t)}&=\frac{2E}{W}+\sin(t)+\frac{1-(2E/W)^2}{(2E/W)-\sin(t)}
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: First of all thanks for reply, how you obteined this relation? What is $a$ ?

Comment: @GiovanniNunziante You're welcome.  My pleasure.  That was a typo that I've corrected.  $a=2E/W$

Comment: yes, now only the third need the  Weierstrass substitution, thank you!

Comment: @GiovanniNunziante Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.